# How to check, that array has size > 1 in Apache FreeMarker?

Tags: java, apache, templates, freemarker

I'm trying to implement template with object, that can be plural.

For example: "There is/are n dog(s)."
When I tried `There <#if dogNames?size>1>is<#else>are</#if> dogNames?size dog<#if dogNames?size>1>s</#if>`, I received exception

> freemarker.core.NonBooleanException: For "#if" condition: Expected a boolean, but this has evaluated to a number (wrapper: f.t.SimpleNumber):
>   ==> dogNames?size

i.e. there is a problem with angle bracket used for comparison.

In [this blog](https://danpersablog.wordpress.com/2010/09/02/freemarker-collection-size-comparation/) it is said that double quotes is enough to escape the bracket, but I'm not managed to do that in Java. When I declared it like this

```
String template = "There <#if dogNames?size\">\"1>is<#else>are</#if> dogNames?size dog<#if dogNames?size>1>s</#if>";
```

and called freemarker api, I received exception

```
freemarker.core.ParseException: Syntax error in template ...:
Encountered "\">\"", but was expecting one of:
"."
".."
<DOT_DOT_LESS>
"..*"
"?"
"??"
"!"
"["
"("
">"
<TERMINATING_EXCLAM>
```

I'm using freemarker 2.3.28, java 8

Answer (score 11, accepted):

You can write `<#if dogNames?size gt 1>`. (See https://freemarker.apache.org/docs/dgui_template_exp.html#dgui_template_exp_comparison)

Comment: Also, according to this link, I can enclose expression in parentheses to let FreeMarker interprets it correctly

Comment: @WeGa Yes, `<#if (dogNames?size > 1)>` also happens to work, because there's no ambiguity in that case. I find it less clean though. Also people often get the wrong idea from it that you have to put the `if` condition into parentheses in general, like Java...

Comment: if dogNames is null, how can we check?

Comment: @egemen Like this: `<#if dogNames!?size gt 1>`. The `!` operator defaults the `null` to an empty string (and empty sequence, hash, etc.).